# Error when installing gtk+-3..2.3

Tags: gtk, compiling

This is the error I get when running the ./configure command in the source folder for gtk+-3.2.3.

[image]

Any help on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `libX11-dev` in this case.

Note, that the best way to compile a custom gtk package is using `apt-get source` and `dpkg-buildpackage`. Use [these steps](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/) as an example.